# Using AJAX DELETE request to clear an array

Tags: javascript, ajax, module

I am trying to send an AJAX DELETE request from my client to my server to empty out an array module.

Here is my client side request:

```
function clearHistory(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/calc',
    data: { method: 'delete'}
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  })
}
```

Here is the server side:

```
app.delete('/calc', (req,res)=>{
    history= [];
    res.sendStatus(201);
})
```

Also on the server side I am importing the history array:

```
let history = require('./modules/history.js');
```

And lastly I have a history array stored in my history.js module:

```
const history = [];

module.exports= history;
```

The array is not emptying as I want it to.  I think my problem is with my data object in the client side request but I do not know enough about AJAX requests to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need to delete item wherever it is stored. Each request will show array in `history.js`

Comment: @charlietfl Can I send the AHAX request to the module ?

Comment: If array is hard coded in history.js it will never change on subsequent requests unless that file gets changed

Comment: @charlietfl the array is constantly being edited

Comment: Sounds like you are assuming the array stays in server memory between requests. It doesn't. Thus the comment that you need to delete it where it is stored

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap `history` array with an object:

**history.js**

```
const history = [];
module.exports = { list: history };
```

And then

```
const history = require('./modules/history.js');
app.delete('/calc', (req,res) =>{
    history.list = [];
    res.sendStatus(201);
})
```